# What do we gain by having "dependent types"?

Tags: logic, type-theory, intuition

I thought I understood dependent typing (DT) properly, but the answer to this question: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30651/why-was-there-a-need-for-martin-l%C3%B6f-to-create-intuitionistic-type-theory has had me thinking otherwise.

After reading up on DT and trying to understand what they are, I'm trying to wonder, what do we gain by this notion of DTs? They seem to be more flexible and powerful than simply typed lambda calculus (STLC), although I can't understand "how/why" exactly.

What is that we can do with DTs that cannot be done with STLC? Seems like adding DTs makes the theory more complicated, but what's the benefit?

From the answer to the above question:

> Dependent types were proposed by de Bruijn and Howard who wanted to
>   extend the Curry-Howard correspondence from propositional to
>   first-order logic.

This seems to make sense at some level, but I'm still unable to grasp the big-picture of "how/why"? Maybe an example explicitly show this extension of the C-H correspondence to FO logic could help hit the point home in understanding what is the big deal with DTs? I'm not sure I comprehend this as well I ought to.

Comment: Have you googled them? Have you heard of Coq, a theorem prover built on dependent types? Did you know that the 4 colour theorem has proven using Coq?

Comment: I did actually. What is hard to Google is what is that extra "power" (for lack of a better word) that DTs lend to type theory, intuitively speaking?

Comment: Why? Dependent types allow you to type more programs while still being type-safe. How? By parameterising types with programs.

Comment: @MartinBerger - Can you please elaborate on "more programs"? What "more" can I do or need, from a theoretical standpoint?

Comment: @DaveClarke - I thought I updated my edit. Not so. My bad. Yes, I'm aware of Coq and its reliance/use on DTs. What I'm trying to look for is the 'meta' behind it - why DTs? What did DTs make possible that otherwise wasn't? It seems Coq's owes its existence to DTs in some way, and I just can't put a finger on it.

Comment: @DaveClarke That Coq, with its fancy types, has been used to do fancy things doesn't imply that those fancy things require those fancy types. For example [Twelf](http://twelf.org/) has had major successes (such as a proof of correctness of SML), and it's only second-order, not higher-order. I've seen some pretty big systems proved with first-order logic only.

Comment: @DaveClarke "Dependent types allowed Coq to prove something that had already been proven 30 years earlier and then re-proven ten years earlier" isn't the greatest advert.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Try proving the same thing just using the simply typed lambda calculus.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Also, the Coq proof is a proof you can trust. Machine checked!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Expanding my comment: Dependent types can type more programs. "More" simply means that the set of programs typable with dependent types is a proper superset of the programs typable in the simply-typed $\lambda$-calculus (STLC). An example would be $List_{2*3+4}(\alpha)$, the lists  of length $10$, carrying elements of type $\alpha$. The expression $2*3+4$ is at the same time a program and part of a type. You cannot do this in the STLC.

The key rule that distinguishes dependent from non-dependent types is application:

$$
\newcommand{\TYPES}[3]{#1 \vdash #2 : #3}
\newcommand{\SUBST}[2]{\{#1/#2\}}
\frac{
   \TYPES{\Gamma}{\color{red}{M}}{A \rightarrow B} 
      \qquad
   \TYPES{\Gamma}{\color{red}{N}}{A}  }{
 \TYPES{\Gamma}{\color{red}{MN}}{B}   }
      \qquad
\frac{
   \TYPES{\Gamma}{{\color{red}M}}{\Pi x^A. B} 
      \qquad
   \TYPES{\Gamma}{\color{red}{N}}{A}  }{
 \TYPES{\Gamma}{{\color{red}{MN}}}{B\SUBST{{\color{red}N}}{x}}   }
$$

On the left you have the STLC, where programs in the premises 'flow' only  into the program of the conclusion. In contrast, in the dependent application rule on the right, the program $N$ from the right premise 'flows' into the *type* in the conclusion$^1$.

In order to be able to parameterise types by programs, the syntax of dependent types must be richer, and to ensure that types are well-formed we use a second 'typing system' called kinds that constrains the types. This kinding system is essentially the STLC, but "one level up".

There are many explanations of dependent types. Some examples.

- [Dependent Types at Work](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~peterd/papers/DependentTypesAtWork.pdf), by Bove and Dybjer.
- Dependent Types, by Aspinall and Hofmann.
- [Dependently Typed Programming in Agda](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/darcs/AFP08/LectureNotes/AgdaIntro.pdf), by Norell and Chapman.
- [Lambda Calculi with Types](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/barendregt.pdf), by Barendregt.

---

$^1$  <sup>In terms of colours: with non-dependent types, black expressions in the conclusion are constructed from black expressions in the premises while
red   expressions in the conclusion are constructed from red expressions in the premises. With dependent types the colours can be mixed by having black parts of the conclusion being constructed from red and black parts of the premise.</sup>

Comment: Now, THAT makes a lot of sense. It may have been obvious but for some reason I couldn't lay a finger on it. Appreciate the transition from comment to answer. Unfortunately, the question has been voted for closing, but I'm glad for the answer :)

Comment: I'm not crazy about your example, since list length is just something you could erase in types and get programs talking about ordinary (un-indexed) lists. It might be useful to note that there are types that do *not* remain well-typed after this kind of erasure, e.g. a program of type $\mathrm{Arr}\ n$, where $\mathrm{Arr}\ 0 = \mathrm{nat}$ and $\mathrm{Arr}\ (n+1) = \mathrm{nat}\rightarrow\mathrm{Arr}\ n$.

Comment: @cody I'm not sure what you mean. Dependent types have (or can be set
up to have) type erasure in the following sense: for all typeable P:
$P\Downarrow V$ iff $erase(P)\Downarrow erase(V)$, where $\Downarrow$ is the
*run-time* reduction relation. (This is a simplified description where the
function erase maps programs with type annotation to 'the same'
programs without annotation.) Maybe you mean something different?

Comment: @MartinBerger: yes in this case I'm talking about erasing dependencies in dependent types to get simple types. The only example I can point to right now is the proof that $F_\omega$ normalizes iff $\mathrm{CoC}$ normalizes (in e.g. [Barendregt's book](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/barendregt.pdf)).

Comment: @cody I think it's unusual to call this type erasure. What's a better name? Maybe type simplification?

Comment: Dependency erasure? It's a common technique to reduce a problem about dependent types to something about simple types (like typeability of un-annotated terms in $\lambda\Pi$).

Answer (score 1):

Think of type declarations as nothing more than assertions.  Currently, all you can say is things like isInt32(), isCharPtr(), etc.  These various assertions are chosen to be checkable at compile-time.  But this concept can be expanded to things like:  isCharPtr() && isNotNull().  Nullable pointers are a huge problem.  Pointers should not be nullable as the default stance, with nullable pointers being a type that isn't dereferenceable without knowing whether it is null or not.  Similar problems are things like: isPositiveInteger(), or isEvenNaturalNumber().